# How to put logical or in autoconf m4 AS_IF

Tags: autoconf, m4

In the official documentation the AS_IF macro is described pretty much like:

```
Macro: AS_IF (test1, [run-if-true1], ..., [run-if-false])
```

How can I make `test1` include several conditions?  (combination of "logical and" and "logical or")

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test1` is just a bash command. So it should be used as a regular bash code. For example:

```
AS_IF ([test "x$a" == "xb" || test "x$a" == "xc"], [echo "test passed"], [echo "test has not passed"]
```

Comment: Due to "||" and "&&" being somewhat "special", I believe "-o" and "-a" are preferred.

Comment: The TL;DR of the bash-hackers.org article is: `-o` and `-a` probably lead to more confusion, since 1) they don't shortcut and 2) there's undefined behaviour on more than four arguments. Use `&&` and `||` instead.